# Batch script to parse json for batch-write-item

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, batch-file

I am very new to batch scripting and while working with the AWS CLI for dynamodb batch-write-item I encountered a limitation of 25 Put/Delete requests.

I have a requirement where i need to update all the items in my dynamodb table with the put requests present in my json file. My json file has let's say 40 put requests.

How can I parse the json object and loop through first 25 and use it with the cli given below?

```
aws dynamodb batch-write-item <json output from above>
```

Further keep looping the same until I reach end of the line.

In linux bash script I do see jq which is used extensively. Is there similar tool that I can use for windows or can we achieve this using pure batch script.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: For Windows I've used [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) and `jq` is one of the packages.  I'm not sure if that helps as you'd need to install that anywhere you need to use the command.

Comment: `jq` is not a native tool in Linux,
you can download it for windows too.
It's a good idea to parse JSON using `jq`,
and it would be a bad idea to try to do that using Bash/Batch.
You can filter and extract parts from the JSON in a format that is easy to consume by Bash/Batch for executing commands.

Comment: Hi janos, thanks for the suggestion of jq. Can you please provide any sample example for building logic using for loop in Batch scripting?

Comment: if you know node is already installed on the users machines you could use it to get the json data... (would not need an additional install of jq)
I do it like `myElements=$(util-json.sh get-keys path.to.what.I.want)` while util-json.sh only has a `node /path/to/util-json.js "$@"`
I can share the code of util-json.js if you are intersted

Comment: @daKmoR: Thanks for the reply. I was able to achieve the result by calling my java class file through batch script, however, I am actually looking for a way to do it only through windows command line batch script and jq.